# Angular 4 Children router not loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my application I had three components that I used to show with router.

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
   { path: '', component: HomeListComponent },
   { path: 'badge', component: BadgeListComponent},
   { path: 'badge-form', component: BadgeFormComponent },
   { path: 'badge-form/:id', component: BadgeFormComponent }
]);
```

Because I wanted to have something like this `/badge/badge-form` in url instead of `/badge-form` when I go to the form I changed my routing config to :

```
{ path: '', component: HomeListComponent },
{
    path: 'badge',
    component: BadgeListComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'badge-form', component: BadgeFormComponent },
        { path: 'badge-form/:id', component: BadgeFormComponent }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working and I can't manage to find why, it's always loading the `BadgeListComponent` even if I go to the `/badge/badge-form` url.

HTML code for BadgeListComponent :

```
<div class="material-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--border">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{ title }}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="list-card-body">
    <table class="data-table-format">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>badgeNumber</th>
          <th>authorizationLevel</th>
          <th>endOfValidity</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let badge of pagedItems" (click)="editBadge(badge.badge_badgeNumber)">
          <th>{{ badge.badge_badgeNumber }}</th>
          <th>{{ badge.badge_authorizationLevel }}</th>
          <th>{{ badge.badge_endOfValidity }}</th>
          <td width="5%" (click)="deleteConfirmation(badge.badge_badgeNumber); $event.stopPropagation();">
            <i class="material-icons delete-data-icon">delete_forever</i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- pager -->
  <div class="mdl-paging" *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length">
    <button [disabled]="pager.currentPage === 1"
      class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon"
      (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">
      <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>
    </button>
    <a *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" 
      [class.selected]="pager.currentPage === page"
      class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon"
      (click)="setPage(page)">
      {{ page }}
    </a>
    <button [disabled]="pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages" 
      class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon"
      (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">
      <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
    </button>
    <br />
    <span class="paginationStats">Pages {{ pager.startPage }}-{{ this.pager.endPage }} of {{ pager.totalPages }}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <div class="buttonHolder">
      <button routerLink="../badge-form" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--primary" *ngIf="!editing">
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your html codes for `BadgeListComponent`?

Comment: @ulubeyn I've added the html code of BadgeListComponent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you navigate to `/badge/badge-form`, your current configuration tells Angular Router to render the `BadgeListComponent` by matching `/badge`, then render `BadgeFormComponent` within `BadgeListComponent`'s `<router-outlet>`.

You need a componentless route to only render the children.

```
{ path: '', component: HomeListComponent },
{
    path: 'badge',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: BadgeListComponent },
        { path: 'badge-form', component: BadgeFormComponent },
        { path: 'badge-form/:id', component: BadgeFormComponent }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you. But is it normal that it's not working the other way ? As all tutorial and official doc do the way I did.

Comment: @ImadElHitti It's working as intended. For example you might want your `badge` module to have a module-specific header/navigation on each page. In that case you do the routing as you did previously, put the shared code in the top-level component, then add a `<router-outlet>` to mark where you want the children rendered within your top-level component. You can effectively create a whole tree of components just by specifying routing rules.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any errors in your `BadgeFormComponent`? It may be blocking the transition between components and let you stick in the parent component `BadgeListComponent`.

By the way, I suggest you to switch the children routes like this:

```
...
children: [
    { path: 'badge-form/:id', component: BadgeFormComponent },
    { path: 'badge-form', component: BadgeFormComponent }
]
...
```

Because Angular Router takes the first route that matches one of the paths. Since you have paths with and without parameter, I guess parameter is optional.

Let me know if you have some issues in your `BadgeFormComponent`.

Comment: Yes I had the param path above, but switched thinking it might be the problem. I've added a gif so you can see when I pass from badge to badge/badge-form, my console stay clear and no errors. Although, I've noticed that when I go to the url it's a bit slow knowing that it should be an SPA application.